# Prove limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If $s_n \neq 0$ and $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\right|$, then by the definition of limit, we have $\forall n>N \implies \left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}-L\right| < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$. If $L < 1$, how do I start the proof?
The goal is to prove that if $L < 1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = 0$. The book says that I have to pick $a$, which is $L < a < 1$. Any hints?

Comment: It's not necessary to add !! at the end of your question titles.

Comment: The sentence "by the definition of limit, we have $\forall n>N\implies\ldots$" doesn't make mathematical sense. You might want to work on understanding what the definition of "limit" really says (sans quantifiers, because they can be confusing at first).

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to start by learning the precise and correct definition of limit of a sequence. The book already gave you the appropriate hint. Show that by picking the correct $\epsilon$ you can insure that $0<\left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\right|<a$ for all $n>N$. Now give an explicit bound on $s_k$ in terms of $s_{N+1}$ for all $k\ge N+1$.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: I don't understand what I misunderstood about the limit definition. Isnt it if for all natural number n greater than N implies the distance between the sequence and the limit is less than some epsilone, then the sequence has the given limit. Is this wrong??

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large%
\forall\ \epsilon >0,\ \exists N\ \ni\ n > N \Longrightarrow
\left\vert{\,s_{n + 1} \over s_{n}} - L\,\right\vert < \epsilon
}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what's going on. Suppose that $L=0.77$. We are told that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=L.$$

So after a while, the ratio $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ is real close to $0.77$. In particular, after a while the ratio is always less than $0.9$.

What does after a while mean? Say it means for $n\ge 1000$. Let $|a_{1000}|=b$.

Since $\left|\frac{a_{1001}}{a_{1000}}\right|\lt 0.9$, we have
$$|a_{10001}|\lt 0.9b.$$

Since $\left|\frac{a_{1002}}{a_{1001}}\right|\lt 0.9$, we have
$$|a_{1002}|\lt (0.9)(0.9b)=(0.9)^2 b.$$

Similarly, $|a_{1003}|\lt (0.9)^3 b$, and in general 
$$|a_{1000+k}|\lt (0.9)^k b.$$

But $(0.9)^k\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, so $|a_n|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. This implies that $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since
$$
L=\lim_n\left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\right|,
$$
there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
L-\varepsilon \le \left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\right| \le L+\varepsilon \quad \forall n \ge N.
$$ 
If $0 \le L<1$, then there exists $\delta \in (L,1)$. Choosing $\varepsilon=\delta-L$ we get
$$
0 \le |s_n| \le |s_N|\delta^{n-N} \quad \forall n \ge N.
$$
Taking the limit we get $\lim_n|s_n|=0$, i.e. $\lim_ns_n=0$.

Comment: Can someone tell me the reason of the downvote?

Comment: It seems ok to me!! But I dont understand how did you $0 \geq |s_n| \geq s_N \delta^{n-N}$. Can you explain this to me please?? Thanks!!